what is wrong with the TextRecognizer code? fails with tflite XMNPack or policy_tflite_dynamite_
I am unable to get textrecognizer to work either on emulator or on a device. (Update: able to recognize text now, but, the callbacks for success, failure, completion are not hit). Why the Listeners are not getting called is the question left open here now.
Detailed emulation log below:
E  E0000 00:00:1724073964.320499   26206 tflite_wrapper.cc:768] INTERNAL: RET_CHECK failure (intelligence/mobile_acceleration/support_library/tflite_wrapper.cc:768) delegate_plugin_ Could not create XNNPack plugin. Have you linked in the XNNPack_plugin target?
Stack trace:
2024-08-19 18:56:04.320 26089-26206 native                  com.example.cameraimagetotext        E  E0000 00:00:1724073964.320511   26206 tflite_detector_client_with_shape_cache.cc:193] Failure during initialization of interpreter.
On a real device the error is:
2024-08-19 19:03:49.751 26578-26817 GoogleApiManager        com.example.cameraimagetotext        E  Failed to get service from broker.
java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
The code that gave the above error: (no longer a issue, skip to the newer code added later)

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
        appInfo.metaData.putString("com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES", "ocr")
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            CameraImageToTextTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greetings(
                        ctx=this,
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greetings(ctx:Context?, name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    Text(
        text = recognizeImage(ctx!!),
        modifier
    )
}


fun recognizeImage(ctx:Context): String
{
    val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS)
    var result:String=""
    val image: InputImage
    var visionTextReturned: com.google.mlkit.vision.text.Text? = null

    val file: File = File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/image.bmp")
    val uri: Uri = Uri.fromFile(file)
    var modified=0
    try {
        image = InputImage.fromFilePath (
            /* context = */ ctx,
            /* imageUri = */ uri
            )
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()

        result= "Error" + e.message
        return result
    }

    result +="before"
    recognizer.process(image)
        .addOnSuccessListener { visionText ->
            {
                println("successlistener hit ")
                modified = 1
                visionTextReturned = visionText
                result += visionText.text + " was the result" + visionText.textBlocks.toString()
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            {

                modified = 1
                result+="Could not convert to text"
            }
        }


    println("test" + modified.toString() + result + "textRet: " + (visionTextReturned?.textBlocks
        ?: "null"))
    result += "after"
    println(result)
    return result
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    CameraImageToTextTheme {
        Greetings(name="Android", ctx=null)
    }
}

The above is learner code (learning android dev basics, kotlin, textrecognition all at the same time)
Struggling quite a bit with build.gradle.kts and getting the dependencies and the kotlin way of describing them right.
Updated code:
Now the recognition is working after I added a button and a remembered state, the button updated the remembered state and caused a re-render. When rerender, the text recognition had completed and the text displayed right. But, the "addOnSuccessListener" were never called.
Changes:

Moved the function recognizeImage to a class and instantiated that in MainActivity.
Added a Button and a remembered state that's updated by the button. The button click caused a re-render due to the state change which allowed for a textbox to check and pick the recognized text correctly.
Also updated the build.gradle.kts (trial and error)


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    val recognizer = MyRecognizer()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
        appInfo.metaData.putString("com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES", "ocr")
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            CameraImageToTextTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greetings(
                        ctx=this,
                        recognizer,
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class testclass()
{
    public val count=0


}
@Composable
fun Greetings(ctx:Context?, recognizer: MyRecognizer, name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val reRender = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val result: MutableState<Task<Text>?> = remember {mutableStateOf(recognizer.recognizeImage(ctx!!))}
    println("RAM_DBG: Exception:" + result.value?.exception.toString())
    //println("RAM_DBG: res text:" + result.value?.result?.text)

    if (result.value?.isComplete() == true)
    {
        println ("not null result = " + result.value?.result?.text)
    }
    val textToDisplay: MutableState<String> = remember {mutableStateOf("init val")}
    Column()
    {
        if (result.value != null) {
            println("RAM_DBG:" + result.value.toString() + result.value!!.isSuccessful.toString())

            Text(
                text = textToDisplay.value,
                modifier.weight(1f)
            )


        }

        Button(onClick ={
            if (result.value!!.isSuccessful == false) result.value = recognizer.recognizeImage(ctx!!)
            println("RAM_DBG:" + result.value.toString() + result.value!!.isSuccessful.toString())
            if (result.value!!.isSuccessful == true)
                textToDisplay.value=result.value!!.result?.text.toString()
                reRender.intValue+=1
                        }
        )
        {
            Text("Click me to detect image" )
            modifier.weight(1f)
        }


    }


}

class MyRecognizer {
    fun recognizeImage(ctx: Context): Task<Text>? {

        val options = TextRecognizerOptions.Builder().build()
        val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(options)
        val image: InputImage

        val file: File = File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/image.bmp")
        val uri: Uri = Uri.fromFile(file)

        try {
            image = InputImage.fromFilePath(
                /* context = */ ctx,
                /* imageUri = */ uri
            )
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return null

        }

        val result = recognizer.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { visionText ->
                {
                    println("RAM_DBG: successlistener hit " + visionText.text)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { _ ->
                {
                    println("RAM_DBG: failure hit")

                }
            }
            .addOnCompleteListener { _ ->
                {
                    println("RAM_DBG: complete hit")

                }
            }



        return result


    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    CameraImageToTextTheme {
        Greetings(name="Android", recognizer = MyRecognizer(), ctx=null)
    }
}


Adding a "run" in front of the lambda functions got the listeners working.
Summary of changes:

Recognizer to a class and instantiated in a large scope. (may be not necessary).
updated the build.gradle.kts (multiple trial and errors)
Added a button that updated the remembered state, which caused the "Greetings" to re-render, when the recognized text could be displayed. (TBD: to use a state update directly from the listeners)
Added a "run" in front of the lamda listener functions

